# has_many association does not respect custom inflector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called reason_to_sell. Ruby will pluralize that to reason_to_sells, so I added this:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'reason_to_sell', 'reasons_to_sell'
end
```

This works great in the console:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > "reason_to_sell".pluralize
 => "reasons_to_sell"
```

Each reason to sell belongs to a user:

```
class ReasonToSell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

And of course each user can have many reasons to sell:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reasons_to_sell
```

However, this gives me:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > u.reasons_to_sell
NameError: uninitialized constant User::ReasonsToSell
```

But if I change the user to have many reason to sells, things get better:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > u=User.first ; u.reason_to_sells
 => []
```

So what do I need to do in order to get the reasons_to_sell inflection to work on this model association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
has_many :reasons_to_sell, :class_name => "ReasonToSell"
```

Comment: Thanks Jakub. For anyone else, have a look at the supported options for has_many here: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001316